# Geoserver cascading and fetching projection

Tags: geoserver, wms

I tried to use cascade of WMS from this portal in order to cache wms layers

http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms?request=GetCapabilities

Native for this portal is EPSG:3765, but EPSG:31275 is also supported
But while direct access to WMS returns correct result:

http://geoportal.dgu.hr/wms?layers=DOF&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG%3A31275&BBOX=5578043.9690343,5053103.9883878,5585211.9651635,5060271.9845171&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

cascaded WMS  with exactly the same parameters returns all-white image.
And in documentation of Geoserver it says that while cascading if the requested projection exists on remote server it will serve it from remote server, otherwise it will reproject it.

What could be going wrong, why isn't geoserver just returning correct image from remote service?

Geoserver version used is 2.2.

Comment: It seems that for some reason geoserver decides to flip  X/Y coordinates.
Ie, I got this URL in log when trying to access directly through GWC, rather than Geoserver 
http://geoportal.dgu.hr/ows?SERVICE=WMS&LAYERS=DOF&CRS=EPSG:31275&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&HEIGHT=1034&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=5068858.899999999,5582331.5,5070320.5,5583793.100000001&WIDTH=1034&STYLES=&VERSION=1.3.0

55xxx numbers should be first coordinate (as given in original request), 50Xxxx the second.
So how to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: So I managed to circumevent this by flipping XY order in OL requests. But is there a way to do this natively on Geoserver?

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer provides support for Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Web Map Service (WMS) versions 1.1.1 and 1.3.0. In 1.1.1 geographic coordinate systems specified with the EPSG namespace are defined to have an axis ordering of longitude/latitude. In 1.3.0 the ordering is latitude/longitude.

Your WMS url was for 1.1.1, change it to 1.3.0 and it should all be ok.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that easiest solution for my problem was to add layer directly to GWC via RESTful service, instead of cascading via Geoserver.